# How to show the Button in the bottom of the JScrollPane Inside a JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jscrollpane, jeditorpane

I am working on an application in which I am trying to show a banner in a JFrame. Inside the JFrame, I using a JScrollbar which is using JEditorPane to display content of a HTML page.

```
    public static JFrame ShowBanner() throws IOException {
        int width = 0;
        int height = 0;
        String urlText = null;
        String ScrnResol = getScreenResolution();
        String[] ScreenResolution = ScrnResol.split(",");
        try {
            width = Integer.parseInt(ScreenResolution[0]);
            height = Integer.parseInt(ScreenResolution[1]);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
            logger.error("NumberFormatException: " + nfe.getMessage());
        }
        //Creating Frame
        frmOpt = new JFrame("Banner");
        frmOpt.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frmOpt.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        frmOpt.setUndecorated(true);
        frmOpt.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f));
        frmOpt.setVisible(true);
        frmOpt.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        frmOpt.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        //bringToForeground(getHWND(frmOpt));
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        LayoutManager layout = new FlowLayout();
        panel.setLayout(layout);
        JEditorPane jEditorPane = new JEditorPane();
        jEditorPane.setEditable(false);
        try {
            
            String urlText=IOUtils.toString(BringUpFrame.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("banner.htm"));
            jEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            jEditorPane.setText(urlText);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Exception while executing showBanner: {}", e);
            jEditorPane.setContentType("text/html");
            jEditorPane.setText("<html>Page not found.</html>");
        }
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jEditorPane);
        scrollPane.setColumnHeaderView(createButton());
        jScrollPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        panel.add(jScrollPane);
        frmOpt.add(panel);
        frmOpt.pack();
        frmOpt.setVisible(true);
        return frmOpt;

   }

   private static JPanel createButton() {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f));
        JButton button = new JButton("Close");
        panel.add(button);
        return panel;
    }
```

Currently the view is looking like this:

[image]

As of Now button is displayed on the Top. What I want to do is to put the button in the bottom of the screen. I have tried some layout (BoxLayout and BorderLayout) but view was as per the expection. I can understand that it will be a small change but I am not having much exp in Swing Programming.

Can someone please suggest how can I achieve that.

**Edit**:

Tried suggested changes:

```
JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jEditorPane);
panel.add(jScrollPane);
frmOpt.add(panel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
frmOpt.add(createButton(),BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
```

but it's not coming as expected. Button and html page in JscrollPane are displaying completely separated and Page is also not coming over complete screen.
[image]

Thanks,

Comment: Use the `BorderLayout`. Add the button to the `BorderLayout.PAGE_END. Add the other components to a JPanel and add the panel to the BorderLayout.CENTER.

Comment: @camickr I tried that but both panels are looking complete separated in the view.I want to show button and html content (Jsrollpane) to look like same page.

Comment: @camickr updated the question with screenshot when I tried changes. I had to remove the setDimension of JscrollPage as it was coming over the Button.

Comment: *I want to show button and html content (Jsrollpane) to look like same page* - You don't need all the child panels.  Add the scrollpane to the CENTER and the button to the PAGE_END. Add each component directly to the frame. Read the Swing tutorial on [Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) to understand the rules of the BorderLayout. If you need more help post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. The MRE should NOT do I/O since we don't have access to your file. The MRE will simulate the HTML. you want to use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default layout manager for [the content pane of] `JFrame` is `BorderLayout`. The center component takes up all the remaining space. Hence `BorderLayout` ignores the preferred size of the center component. `FlowLayout`, on the other hand, respects the preferred size of its contained components. Since you have maximized the `JFrame` its center component will take up almost the entire screen so you just need to add the `JScrollPane` to the `BorderLayout` center.

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class ForManish {
    private void createAndDisplayGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setUndecorated(true);
        frame.add(createScrollPane(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(createButtonPanel(), BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        frame.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private JScrollPane createScrollPane() {
        JEditorPane editorPane = new JEditorPane("text/html", "<h1 align=\"center\">Checkout unavailable");
        editorPane.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
        scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f)));
        return scrollPane;
    }

    private JPanel createButtonPanel() {
        JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
        buttonPanel.setBackground(new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.1f));
        JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close");
        buttonPanel.add(closeButton);
        return buttonPanel;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> new ForManish().createAndDisplayGui());
    }
}
```

Comment: is it possible to have the button inside the html page and open a window dialog on the click of button from html ?